# CodeIgniter using same login for different subdomain

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter 2.1.4 for one of my application.

I am sharing all files and folder with different subdomain, but using different database.

Now in this I am getting problem if I login with any one domain than for other subdomain it directly get login.

Like if I login to www.example.com/sub1
than when I go to www.example.com/sub2 it doesn't ask for login it directly use the login of sub1.

How can I prevent this.

Comment: try to also save your session variable into database.

Comment: storing session in db is good suggestion, but is there any other way.

Comment: you can also change session variable name for your subdomain application.

Comment: Why would you like to save $_SESSION in DB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is probably that your sessions have no differentiating factor.

http://www.example.com/sub1 and http://www.example.com/sub2 are not subdomains

If you were using http://sub1.exmaple.com and http://sub2.example.com then your sessions would be fine.

A quick-fix for your issue can be to assign "sub-domain" specific session variables like this:

```
$_SESSION['sub1']['user_id'] = 'value from DB';
```

To log out a user from that "sub-domain" you can use this:

```
unset($_SESSION['sub1']);
```

With this approach you can have people logging into multiple "sub-domains"

In your question you do not specify if you are using CodeIgniter sessions but I would imagine that the same issue/logic applies.

Answer (score 0):

To have different session cookies for each subdomain you should try to differentiate your config files a little bit.

You can have a generic config.php file for each of your subdomains by having something like this in your main `application/config/config.php` file

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

if (!defined('WHATDOMAIN'))
    exit('No domain setup exists for the application');

require_once('sub_domains/config_'.WHATDOMAIN.'.php');

/* End of file config.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/config.php */
```

Then at your index.php of your each domain you initialize the WHATDOMAIN constant so your config.php can find it.

Then you will be able to use different settings for each subdomain thus you can try altering your config name of your session variable at

`application/config/sub_domains/config_WHATDOMAIN.php`

for your each different codeigniter application domain,

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'different_sess_name_goes_here';
```

and achieve the desirable result.